# How to extract numeric characters from character values and delete character values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to extract only the numeric values from the character value in SQL Server.

Details of the data as follows.

like

1. `+/- 0.6 inlbs`(Want to take only 0.6)
2. `38.00 to 42.00`(Want to take only 42.00)
3. .`001" TIR`(Want to take only .001)

This is for SQL SERVER 2014.

The code that I have tried is

```
SUBSTRING(SOOT.[PERF_SPEC],PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',SOOT.[PERF_SPEC]),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SOOT.[PERF_SPEC],'%',''),'[A-Z]',''),'[a-z]',''),LEN(SOOT.[PERF_SPEC])))
```

The expected result is to get the numeric character only

Comment: from`38.00 to 42.00` you want to extract only 42.00? 38.00 is also numeric right?

Comment: We have too little sample data to understand the rules. What if you had a string that contains three different numbers, like `12 minus 2 equals 10`? Please [edit] your question to explain the logic for taking only `42.00` from the second string.